# android libgdx and rotate actions in sequence

Tags: android, rotation, libgdx

I want to spin a wheel for some angle. and then spin it by some small angles.
The rotation should have a slow down inertion. 
For this I create some rotate actions with differing times to rotate the certain angle and then I put it in a sequence.

but while passing from an action to another I can notice pauses.
any suggestions what should I do in order to have a smooth passing between rotations ?

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't it better if you just use one Rotation action along with Interpolator? Interpolator should decrease the amount of rotation in time.

You can write your own Interpolator, or just use existing one:

- AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator
- AccelerateInterpolator
- AnticipateInterpolator
- DecelerateInterpolator
- LinearInterpolator
- OvershootInterpolator

Comment: Actually I have used it, but there were some problems. I have rotated the wheel by let's say 720 degrees and applied AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator. Then I want to rotate it by small angles (30degrees) but in sequentially slowing manner. The thing is that, after rotating 720degrees there is a small pause when passing to 30degrees.